# Apple Aperture Tutorial

Tags: aperture

I am looking for a good Aperture tutorial and would appreciate some recommendations.

Which tutorials can you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

You could start with Apple's free training videos at [Aperture 3 video tutorials](http://support.apple.com/videos/#aperture). Also see the list of [Aperture training resources](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT5253) and general [Aperture resources](http://www.apple.com/aperture/resources/) (including downloads, extras and training).

There are other paid video tutorials from [VTC](http://www.vtc.com), [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com), [Kelby Training](http://kelbytraining.com), etc.